# SQL: Find all combinations with the same index in an array

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in SQL:

| id | vector |
| --- | --- |
| A0 | 1,2,....,10 |
| A1 | 11,12,...,20 |
| A2 | 21,22,...,30 |
| A3 | 31,32,...,40 |

I want to find all combinations of three vectors  where each index in a vector is combined with the same index in a different vector. For example I want to find:

| id1 | id2 | id3 | vector |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A0 | A1 | A2 | 1,11,21 |
| A0 | A1 | A2 | 2,12,22 |
| A0 | A1 | A2 | 3,13,23 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| A1 | A2 | A3 | 19,29,39 |
| A1 | A2 | A3 | 20,30,40 |

I tried the following but this produces all combinations and does not take into account that the indexes of the numbers should match and I am not sure how to fix this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT X.id, EXPLODE(X.vector) FROM vector X),
     (SELECT Y.id, EXPLODE(Y.vector) FROM vector Y),
     (SELECT Z.id, EXPLODE(Z.vector) FROM vector Z),
WHERE X.id < Y.id AND Y.id < Z.id;
```

Another solution I could think of was adding the vectors together like this:

| id1 | id2 | id3 | vector |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A0 | A1 | A2 | (1,2,...,10), (11,12,...,20), (21,22,...,30) |

Then I wanted to transpose the vector so I would get:

| id1 | id2 | id3 | vector |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A0 | A1 | A2 | (1, 11,21), (2,12,22), ..., (19,29,39),(20,30,40) |

But unfortunately SQL does not have a transpose function.

Comment: MySQL has no function named EXPLODE(). What does `SELECT VERSION();` return in your environment?

Comment: Also please try `SELECT current_version();`

Answer (score 0):

There example with recursive parsing (splitting) strings (separated with comma values) to pairs (id,value) without STRING_SPLIT or EXPLODE. Second part - join values by indexes.
Test data

```
create table test (id varchar(2),vector varchar(100));
insert into test values('A0','1,2,10');
insert into test values('A1','11,12,20');
insert into test values('A2','21,22,30');
insert into test values('A3','31,32,40');
```

Recursive CTE. `vector` column in query is optional, only for clarity

```
with recursive  r as(
select 1 i,id,vector
   ,case when length(vector)>0 and locate(',',vector,1)>0 
            then substring(vector,1,locate(',',vector,1)-1)
         when length(vector)>0 then vector
    end v
   ,locate(',',vector,1)+1 idx
   ,case when locate(',',vector,1)>0 then substring(vector,locate(',',vector,1)+1)
    else ''
    end rest
from test
union all 
select  i+1 i,id,vector
 ,case when length(rest)>0 and locate(',',rest,1)>0 
            then substring(rest,1,locate(',',rest,1)-1)
         when length(rest)>0 then rest
    end v
   ,locate(',',rest,1)+1 idx
   ,case when locate(',',rest,1)>0 then substring(rest,locate(',',rest,1)+1)
    else ''
    end rest
from r where length(rest)>0
)
, t as (-- select only necessary columns from recursive CTE
select i,id,v from r
)
select * 
  ,concat('(',t1.id,',',t2.id,',',t3.id,')') ids
  ,concat('(',t1.v,',',t2.v,',',t3.v,')') comb
from t t1 
left  join t t2 on t2.i=t1.i and t2.id>t1.id
left  join t t3 on t3.i=t2.i and t3.id>t2.id and t3.id>t1.id
where t1.i is not null and t2.i is not null and t3.i is not null
```

Result table

| i | id | v | i | id | v | i | id | v | ids | comb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A0 | 1 | 1 | A1 | 11 | 1 | A2 | 21 | (A0,A1,A2) | (1,11,21) |
| 1 | A0 | 1 | 1 | A1 | 11 | 1 | A3 | 31 | (A0,A1,A3) | (1,11,31) |
| 1 | A0 | 1 | 1 | A2 | 21 | 1 | A3 | 31 | (A0,A2,A3) | (1,21,31) |
| 1 | A1 | 11 | 1 | A2 | 21 | 1 | A3 | 31 | (A1,A2,A3) | (11,21,31) |
| 2 | A0 | 2 | 2 | A1 | 12 | 2 | A2 | 22 | (A0,A1,A2) | (2,12,22) |
| 2 | A0 | 2 | 2 | A1 | 12 | 2 | A3 | 32 | (A0,A1,A3) | (2,12,32) |
| 2 | A0 | 2 | 2 | A2 | 22 | 2 | A3 | 32 | (A0,A2,A3) | (2,22,32) |
| 2 | A1 | 12 | 2 | A2 | 22 | 2 | A3 | 32 | (A1,A2,A3) | (12,22,32) |
| 3 | A0 | 10 | 3 | A1 | 20 | 3 | A2 | 30 | (A0,A1,A2) | (10,20,30) |
| 3 | A0 | 10 | 3 | A1 | 20 | 3 | A3 | 40 | (A0,A1,A3) | (10,20,40) |
| 3 | A0 | 10 | 3 | A2 | 30 | 3 | A3 | 40 | (A0,A2,A3) | (10,30,40) |
| 3 | A1 | 20 | 3 | A2 | 30 | 3 | A3 | 40 | (A1,A2,A3) | (20,30,40) |

JOIN condition like `t2.id>t1.id` is necessary to eliminate needless combination - include combination (10,20,30) and exclude (20,10,30) and so on.
If are needed all combinations, change to `t2.id<>t1.id`.